# Find all polynomials $f\in \mathbb R[x]$ such that: $(a)\;xf(x-1)=(x-3)f(x)$ $(b)\;x(x-1)f(x+1)=(x+2)(x+1)f(x-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, real-numbers

> Find all polynomials $f\in \mathbb R[x]$ such that:
>
> $(a)\;xf(x-1)=(x-3)f(x)$
>
> $(b)\;x(x-1)f(x+1)=(x+2)(x+1)f(x-1)$

$$$$
My attempt:

$(a)$

I focused on the form: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

I looked at the leading term $a_nx^n$ on both sides first to set some constraint to the degree, tried to see what happens with the constant $a_0$ when multiplying it by $x\;\&\;(x-3)$ and compare the number of terms on each side:
$$x\cdot a_n(x-1)^n\;\;\&\;\;(x-3)\cdot a_nx^n$$
For $n=2$, I get: $$a_2(x^3-2x^2+x)\;\;\&\;\;a_2(x^3-3x^2)$$ 
$$a_1(x^2-x)\;\;\&\;\;a_1(x^2-3x)$$
$$a_0x\;\;\&\;\;a_0(x-3)$$
It seems $a_0$ doesn't appear on the left side at all, therefore (as far as I'm concerned) it has to be $0$. 
I didn't know how to continue, I was really confused. That was the only conclusion of mine in $(b)$ as well. 
I thought I could rewrite:$$x(x-1)f(x+1)=(x+2)(x+1)f(x-1)$$
$$\text{as}$$

$$(x-1)xf(x+1)=(x+1)(x+2)f(x-1),$$
but it isn't useful since I'm dealing not just with $\mathbb Z$, but $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless $f$ is identically zero, $$\frac{f(x)}{f(x-1)}=\frac{x}{x-3}\implies\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-3)(x-2)}=\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x-1)}=\frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{x(x-1)}$$for $x\notin\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3\}$. This contradiction tells us $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Perhaps this will get you started: for part (a) observe that substituting $x=0$ gives us $f(0)=0$. Likewise $x=3$ gives us $f(2)=0$ and finally $x=2$ gives us $f(1)=0$. Thus the polynomial must be of the form 
$$f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)g(x).$$
Can you proceed from here by substituting this into the given relation and comparing the degrees of both sides?

Try a similar approach with part (b).

Comment: Thank you very much @AnuragA! I'll examine this task further.